Turnover pro Supplier's name in SQL
I have such table and there could be rows with the same supplier's name in both columns.
I want to get turnover pro supplier's name , so that means i cannot create 2 datasets, one with supplier prod and turnover union supplier aus and turnover and sum up the turnover pro supplier's name cause it will sum turnover of 10 twice for Bosch.
How to do it efficient?
desired result is
bosch 12
magna 2

CREATE TABLE TURNOVER_TABLE (
    SUPPLIER_PROD VARCHAR(255),
    SUPPLIER_AUS VARCHAR(255),
    TURNOVER INT
);



INSERT INTO TURNOVER_TABLE (SUPPLIER_PROD, SUPPLIER_AUS, TURNOVER)
VALUES ('Bosch', 'Bosch', 10);


INSERT INTO TURNOVER_TABLE (SUPPLIER_PROD, SUPPLIER_AUS, TURNOVER)
VALUES ('Bosch', 'Magna', 1);


INSERT INTO TURNOVER_TABLE (SUPPLIER_PROD, SUPPLIER_AUS, TURNOVER)
VALUES ('Magna', 'Bosch', 1);


Can you tell us about the desired output?

@Alex Poole , I inserted the desired result


i cannot create 2 datasets, one with supplier prod and turnover union supplier aus and turnover and sum up the turnover pro supplier's name cause it will sum turnover of 10 twice for Bosch

You can restate that as "union supplier aus and turnover where supplier aus is different", so in the second branch of the union you can exclude rows where the suppliers are the same:
select supplier_prod, turnover
from turnover_table
union all
select supplier_aus, turnover
from turnover_table
where supplier_aus != supplier_prod;




SUPPLIER_PROD
TURNOVER




Bosch
10


Bosch
1


Magna
1


Magna
1


Bosch
1



And then aggregate that:
select supplier_prod, sum(turnover) as turnover
from (
  select supplier_prod, turnover
  from turnover_table
  union all
  select supplier_aus, turnover
  from turnover_table
  where supplier_aus != supplier_prod
)
group by supplier_prod;




SUPPLIER_PROD
TURNOVER




Bosch
12


Magna
2



fiddle

I thought it would exclude the row with the turnover from both branches cause the where clause applied to the whole unioned data set

Right. No, that's not how it parses the branches of the union, fortunately. (You can have a where clause in the first branch too; and could swap the branches over).
